# ESP8266 Arduino request content encoding

Tags: c, arduino, urlencode, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I'm trying to send JSON to an Arduino module with a ESP8266. I have a simple web server, which waiting for JSON with SSID and password where device must connect.

```
ESP8266WebServer server(80);
server.on("/config", HTTP_POST, configHandle);
server.begin();

void handleConfig() {
    String payload = server.arg("plain");
    //convert JSON to char[]
    //parse using jsmn lib
}
```

What if password contains non ASCII characters? How can I handle request content to put this arguments to method:

```
WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
```

**Edit:**

Example: If I send JSON like:

```
{"pass": "test+test"}
```

Then, when I print this payload I don't get a `+` sign (but this is ASCII sign)

Request (wireshark):

[image]

Char array payload from board:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ESP8266WebServer` library is decoding `+` into a space character.

You need to URL encode the JSON string, before sending it.

In vanilla JavaScript you need to use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).
Don't use [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI), because it doesn't encode `+`.
Whatever you use, make sure the `+` character is encoded into `%2b`.

This will also save you from potential problems, involving `?`, `&` and `=` inside your JSON.

Comment: JSON is sent in request payload POST method. So, i really should encode this content using URI encoding method? Why library changing + to space character, and how prevent this solution?

Comment: [POST data must also be encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)#Use_for_submitting_web_forms)

Comment: ok, when encode this json, works fine, but is some method to read this data from client connection stream using original bytes?